# Why doesn't ogr2ogr's -nln flag have any effect on output GeoJSON in some cases?

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr

Here is an example GeoJSON, `example.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "example",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

I am processing it with [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html). Here is an example command:

```
ogr2ogr example_processed.geojson example.geojson -nln exampleLayerName
```

`example_processed.geojson` becomes (with comment added):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "example", // <- why is this not "exampleLayerName" instead?
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

The [documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-nln) of the `-nln` flag:

> `-nln <name>`
>
> Assign an alternate name to the new layer

**Why is then the layer still called `example`, and not `exampleLayerName` in `example_processed.geojson`?**

Another example, where the `-nln` flag does actually have an effect:

`exmaple.geojson`:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

Then:

```
ogr2ogr example_processed.geojson example.geojson -nln exampleLayerName
```

`cat example_processed.geojson` (+ added comment):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "exampleLayerName",  // <- as expected!
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "a" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "data": "b" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1.0, 1.0 ] } }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you have found a bug. If you convert GeoJSON data that has already name set, then ogr2ogr does not change the name even if the option `-nln` is used.

The name is set as an optional property at feature collection level:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Lufthavn",
...
```

I made a test by converting such data into GeoJSON and the name remained as "Lufthavn" even with the `-nln` option. Then I dropped the name by converting data into JML format that does not support internal layer names. In a conversion from this name-free data the `-nln` switch is honored.

```
ogr2ogr -f jml norge.jml norge.json
ogr2ogr example_processed.geojson norge.jml -nln exampleLayerName

ogrinfo example_processed.geojson

INFO: Open of `example_processed.geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.
1: exampleLayerName (Point)
```

The GeoJSON driver has a layer creation option WRITE_NAME https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html. Setting it explicitly into YES did not help with renaming the layer. That is not a surprise because YES is documented to be the default. However, WRITE_NAME does work for removing the name property.

```
ogr2ogr example_processed.geojson norge.json -nln exampleLayerName -lco WRITE_NAME=NO
```

The result is only partly right because the old name is wiped away but the new name is not written. When the name property is missing then GDAL generates the layer name from the file name.

```
ogrinfo example_processed.geojson

INFO: Open of `example_processed.geojson'
      using driver `GeoJSON' successful.
1: example_processed (Point)
```

I think that this case is so evidently a bug that you can create a bug report in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/new. Add a link to your question.

Comment: Nice! Creating the bug report...

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/6920.

Comment: The bug has been fixed with PR https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/6923.

Answer (score 3):

From the GeoJSON spec: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946

```
6.1.  Foreign Members

   Members not described in this specification ("foreign members") MAY
   be used in a GeoJSON document.  Note that support for foreign members
   can vary across implementations, and no normative processing model
   for foreign members is defined.  Accordingly, implementations that
   rely too heavily on the use of foreign members might experience
   reduced interoperability with other implementations.
```

the key "name" is not a default in the specification, hence it falls into the case described here (6.1). Therefore, chances are high than implementers, as GDAL, won't treat this information at all, mainly for interoperability reasons.

After some researches, GDAL seems to implement this but it's apparently not working in the case of a *renaming* operation (only during layer creation; i.e. if your input layer doesn't have a name, it will create it on the other hand): https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#vector-geojson

[image]

Source: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#layer

I also tried using the `-overwrite` flag but it says:

```
ERROR 1: Layer 'exampleLayerName' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
```

Anyway, until a fix is out, you can still process this field manually, with whatever parser of your choice.

Comment: The strange thing is, sometimes it seemed to have an effect. Maybe I was wrong, I couldn't recreate an example now when it did matter. If I can, I'll post it.

Comment: Oh yep, found one. Updating question in a moment...